# Getting javax.transaction.HeuristicMixedException

Tags: java, jms, websphere, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I am running a Spring Batch on IBM WebSphere and encountered below exception in application log:

```
UOWManager transaction processing failed; nested exception is com.ibm.wsspi.uow.UOWException: javax.transaction.HeuristicMixedException
    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager.execute(WebSphereUowTransactionManager.java:313)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:134)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:273)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:82)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:258)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:208)
    at com.im.batch.integration.partition.IMTaskExecutorPartitionHandler$PartitionTaskCallable.call(IMTaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:63)
    at com.im.batch.integration.partition.IMTaskExecutorPartitionHandler$PartitionTaskCallable.call(IMTaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:277)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.commonj.DelegatingWork.run(DelegatingWork.java:63)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.J2EEContext.run(J2EEContext.java:1178)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.WorkWithExecutionContextImpl.go(WorkWithExecutionContextImpl.java:199)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.CJWorkItemImpl.run(CJWorkItemImpl.java:236)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
Caused by: com.ibm.wsspi.uow.UOWException: javax.transaction.HeuristicMixedException
    at com.ibm.ws.uow.embeddable.EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.runUnderNewUOW(EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.java:823)
    at com.ibm.ws.uow.embeddable.EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.runUnderUOW(EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.java:370)
    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager.execute(WebSphereUowTransactionManager.java:306)
    ... 16 more
```

In sysout logs I am getting below error on the same time:

```
javax.transaction.xa.XAException: The method 'xa_commit' has failed with errorCode '-7' due to the resource being closed.
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiXAResource.commit(JmqiXAResource.java:460)
    at com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSManagedSession$JMSXAResource.commit(JMSManagedSession.java:1444)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.XATransactionWrapper.commit(XATransactionWrapper.java:496)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.JTAXAResourceImpl.commit(JTAXAResourceImpl.java:308)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.RegisteredResources.deliverOutcome(RegisteredResources.java:1644)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.RegisteredResources.distributeOutcome(RegisteredResources.java:2003)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.RegisteredResources.distributeCommit(RegisteredResources.java:2315)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TransactionImpl.internalCommit(TransactionImpl.java:1911)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TransactionImpl.internalCommit(TransactionImpl.java:1887)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TransactionImpl.coreStage2CommitProcessing(TransactionImpl.java:1134)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TransactionImpl.stage2CommitProcessing(TransactionImpl.java:1172)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TransactionImpl.processCommit(TransactionImpl.java:1033)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:963)
    at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.TranManagerImpl.commit(TranManagerImpl.java:439)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TranManagerSet.commit(TranManagerSet.java:191)
    at com.ibm.ws.uow.UOWManagerImpl.uowCommit(UOWManagerImpl.java:807)
    at com.ibm.ws.uow.embeddable.EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.uowEnd(EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.java:881)
    at com.ibm.ws.uow.UOWManagerImpl.uowEnd(UOWManagerImpl.java:782)
    at com.ibm.ws.uow.embeddable.EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.runUnderNewUOW(EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.java:818)
    at com.ibm.ws.uow.embeddable.EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.runUnderUOW(EmbeddableUOWManagerImpl.java:370)
    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager.execute(WebSphereUowTransactionManager.java:306)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:134)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:273)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:82)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:258)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:208)
    at com.im.batch.integration.partition.IMTaskExecutorPartitionHandler$PartitionTaskCallable.call(IMTaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:63)
```

I have checked Aged Time out on websphere =0

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/transaction/HeuristicMixedException.html

Comment: What resources are you enlisting in your XA transaction? What investigation have you done to find the root-cause of the error?

Comment: We are basically inserting data into the db and then sending msg on MQ   using JMS. 
From exception we are seeing that resource is not available (JMS resource).